# How to I gather all the responses from all emit callbacks?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, callback, socket.io

I have a three-way socket.io project that uses a `relay` server to `emit` commands to a `hub controller` which `on` a `relay` emission will `emit` to all the nodes.

> My question is how do I gather **all** the responses from all the connected nodes, using `emit's` callback?

That callback is going to fire multiple times, once for every node connected. Is there a way to collect every response and send them to the initial emit callback.

Here's the code for each step along the way.

```
// RELAY MESSAGING CLIENT (SENDS MESSAGES TO ADMIN)

io.emit("pricing-relay", {
  sku: "AMZ-PROD"
}, function(errString, responsesFromAllNodes){
  // response from `socket.on("pricing-relay"`)
  // console.log(responsesFromAllNodes)
  /*
     [
        "invalid something", null,
        null, true,
        null, false,
        "invalid something", null,
        null, true,
     ]
  */
})

// HUB CONTROLLER SERVER (DISTRIBUTES TO ALL CONNECTED NODES)

socket.on("pricing-relay", function(data, callback){
  var responses = []
  io.emit("pricing", data, function(errString, response){
    response.push([errString, response])
    // when these are all done responding
    // send callback(null, responses)
  })
})

// DRONE CLIENT (PIECE EXECUTING ASYNC CODE)

io.on("pricing", function(data, callback){
  return changepricing(data, function(err, result){
    if(err) return callback(err.message, result)
    return callback(null, result)
  })
})
```

Comment: Turns out `Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting